# Lorentzian fit two ways of writing a code

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting, lmfit

I am struggling right now with Lorentzian curve fit. I'll try to explain my problem. I need to write my own code for Lorentzian curve fit so I can add some stuff to the equations. I've implemented Lorentzian fit with `model` and `def`, I've written similary, but it doesn't work. Check out my code:

So here are my data:

```
for dataset in [Bxfft]:
    dataset = np.asarray(dataset)
    freqs, psd = signal.welch(dataset, fs=266336/300, window='hamming', nperseg=16192, scaling='density')
    plt.semilogy(freqs[30:-7000], psd[30:-7000]/dataset.size**0, color='r', label='Bx')
    x = freqs[100:-7900]
    y = psd[100:-7900]
```

Here is Lorentzian curve fit defined by me:

```
def lorentzian(x, amp, cen, sig):
    return (amp/np.pi) * (sig/(x-cen)**2 + sig**2)

model = Model(lorentzian)
pars = model.make_params(amp=6, cen=5, sig=1)
pars['amp'].max = 6
result = model.fit(y, pars, x=x)
final_fit = result.best_fit
print(result.fit_report(min_correl=0.25))
plt.plot(x, final_fit, 'k--', linewidth=3)
```

And here done by model function:

```
model2 = LorentzianModel()
params2 = model2.make_params(amplitude=6, center=5, sigma=1)
params2['amplitude'].value = 6
result2 = model2.fit(y, params2, x=x)
final_fit2 = result2.best_fit
print(result2.fit_report(min_correl=0.25))
plt.plot(x, final_fit2, 'k--', linewidth=3)
```

The upper plot goes for `def` Lorentzian, and the lower plot goes for `model` Lorentzian.

And that's a result:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look like a parenthesis problem. This:

```
(amp/np.pi) * (sig/(x-cen)**2 + sig**2)
```

is not a Lorentzian. This:

```
(amp/np.pi) * (sig/((x-cen)**2 + sig**2))
```

is. In addition you may have a slight integer problem in the rare event `cen,x,sig` are all integers. You can use `math.pow` to solve this, or what they do in `lmfit` and multiply `x` by a float: `1.0*x-cen`.

As a side note, `lmfit` for some reason writes this function equivalently but [a bit differently](https://github.com/lmfit/lmfit-py/blob/master/lmfit/lineshapes.py) (find on page lorentzian). I don't see a reason for this though.

Comment: It still amaze me that, parenthesis can change the whole thing :) Thank You for your advice.

Comment: @kabanus - If I am not mistaken, the definition of Lorentzian used by lmfit is equivalent to the one here (with correct parentheses, of course) for an Amplitude times a unit-normalized Lorentzian.

Comment: @MNewville you are correct. I didn't mean it wasn't, just that the actual expression calculating the same thing differs. I think it's even worse (more division) from a programming view point. Anyway I'll clarify my meaning, thanks.